# How do you change a drag-and-dropped image mid-drag?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsdraggingitem

So I want to drag an object from one source to multiple potential destinations. When the object is over each destination, I want it to 'morph' into a different image. Is there a straightforward way to do this from the NSDragSource perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this using just the drag source APIs.

If you look at Interface Builder it does something similar to what you want. When you drag a button out of the library the button animates in the middle of the drag.

According to most people the way Apple is doing this is by making the drag image a small transparent image. Then they create a Window and have it follow the mouse. You can then use the window to do any type of animation you want.

Comment: At least as of 10.7+ the accepted response is no longer correct -  see Иван Георгиев answer for the current way to change stuff mid-drag!

Answer (score 19):

You can do so by using `enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:` method of `NSDraggingInfo` in your dragging destination's handler methods (i.e. - your implementation of `NSDraggingDestination` protocol).

For example:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    NSImage* newDragImage = <take it from wherever>;
    [sender enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:0
                                      forView:sender.draggingSource
                                      classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]]
                                searchOptions:nil
                                   usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                       NSRect theFrame = draggingItem.draggingFrame;
                                       theFrame.size = newDragImage.size;
                                       [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:theFrame contents:newDragImage];
                                       *stop = NO;
                                   }];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Joshua Nozzi has posted a great way to do this: http://joshua.nozzi.name/2009/10/jlndrageffectmanager/

Comment: Yep. This is a drop-in manager for this particular effect. The download contains a demo app.

Comment: If you end up using this class, just let me know and I'll add your app to the list on the source page.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Check out NSDraggingInfo's enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions method.

Comment: Please edit your answer to elaborate: How would you use that method to solve this problem?